# SObjectException: Field is not writeable: User.ProfileId

Tags: apex, community, portal

Im creating a community user from an Apex code. When our internal users (non-admins) run the code they are getting following error. (This was working fine when we test the feature in sandbox)

> SObjectException: Field is not writeable: User.ProfileId

The code is

```
    //Grab Community User Profile
    Profile p = [Select Id, Name from Profile where Name = :COMMUNITY_PROFILE LIMIT 1]; 

    User PortalUser = new User();

        PortalUser.UserName = Con.Email+'-POC';
        PortalUser.ContactId = Con.Id;
        PortalUser.ProfileId = p.id;
        PortalUser.Email = Con.Email;
        PortalUser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        PortalUser.FirstName = Con.FirstName;
        PortalUser.LastName = Con.LastName;
        PortalUser.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        PortalUser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        PortalUser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';

        if (Con.LastName.length() >= 8){
            PortalUser.Alias = Con.LastName.substring(0, 7);    
        }else{
            PortalUser.Alias = Con.LastName;
        }   

        SObjToInsert.add(PortalUser);
```

Comment: Your class written "with Sharing" or "Without Sharing" ?

Comment: I have removed "With Sharing" too.
public class GT_ActivationServices {}

But still have the issue

Comment: it looks like field level permission issue. Check if system admin have field level permission set properly.

Comment: Thanks, it works well for system admins. But the issue is when it runs by other internal users.

Comment: What is your API version?

Comment: **it works well for system admins. But the issue is when it runs by other internal users.** means you want to created user in context of community user ?

Comment: you dont want to use the standard **Site.createPortalUser()** ?

Comment: @Ratan not in context of community user. But other non-admin internal users

Comment: @susanoochidori API version is 36

Comment: Does you internal user profile has permission "Manage Internal Users"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding 'without sharing' to all my framework classes which leads to create the portal user.

Comment: Solved my issues as well!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same type of issue. Without changing any code not able to create a user via APEX. In my case, I reduce API version. So API version lesser than 34 (<= 33) should fix this issue.

Comment: Fixed my issue. I still think there's something wrong with the code but this helps for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your objects settings + field settings of that object in the profile(s) of the user. You need to see if it is writeable and that the field is also editable. If not, you need to enable it.

If there are more users with that profile and you don't want to give all of them access to the field, you can create a permission set and assign it to the users. You can also create a group and assign a permission set to it and then you can add the users you want to have access to the field in the group.

Comment: Thanks. But non Admin profiles has right to edit the ProfileId field on User object. Having said that it worked well previously and in FSB too